# Error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)

Tags: swift

Please tell me the application crashes with an error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)
```

when clicking on the button for reminders for a table cell (switching to a new View Controller).
The error appears in the class when creating a UILabel in the line `let label = UILabel ()`:

```
let oneLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)
        label.numberOfLines = 4
    }
    else {
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
        label.numberOfLines = 1
    }
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

Here is the code from another class that transitions to the View Controller, for which the UILabel is created:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let alarm = UIContextualAction(
            style: .normal,
            title: "",
        handler: {(_, _, completion) in
            self.notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                guard granted else { return DispatchQueue.main.async { self.createAlertForNotifications() } }
                self.notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                    guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let vc = OneViewController()
                            self.parentController!.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
                    }
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
        )
        alarm.image = ListImages.alarmImage
        alarm.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [alarm])
    }
```

Sometimes this error appears, sometimes not, and it may appear for the second UILabel, which is created after the first. How can you fix this error?

Comment: please share the code where you are using oneLabel in oneViewController

Comment: That error means you dereference an invalid pointer, where the cause of this is not obvious. Not sure if this fixes your problem, but your handler does not call the completion handler on every paths. Completion handlers must be called eventually. You may try to call `completion(false)` where you didn't call it.

Comment: I have attached the code in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get error in `let dataPicker = UIDatePicker()`

Here you go to the OneViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let oneObject = isFiltering ? filteredObjects[indexPath.row] : listObjects[indexPath.row]
        let alarm = UIContextualAction(
            style: .normal,
            title: "",
        handler: {(_, _, completion) in
            self.notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                guard granted else { return DispatchQueue.main.async { self.createAlertForNotifications() } }
                self.notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                    guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let vc = OneViewController()
                            ListNameLabel.oneText = oneObject.name
             self.parentController!.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
                    }
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
        )
        alarm.image = ListImages.alarmImage
        alarm.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [alarm])
    }
```

This is class with UILabel:

```
import UIKit
class MainView: UIView {
    let oneLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)
            label.numberOfLines = 4
        }
        else {
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
            label.numberOfLines = 1
        }
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
let sheduleTimeDataPicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let dataPicker = UIDatePicker()
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        dataPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        }
    else {
        dataPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
    }
    dataPicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    dataPicker.date = Date()
    dataPicker.minimumDate = Date()
    dataPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return dataPicker
}()
    let oneView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(oneView)
        oneView.addSubview(oneLabel)
        oneView.addSubview(sheduleTimeDataPicker)
        
        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
            // oneLabel constraints
            oneLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            oneLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
            oneLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            oneLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
            // sheduleTimeDataPicker constraints
        sheduleTimeDataPicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        sheduleTimeDataPicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        else {
            // oneLabel constraints
            oneLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            oneLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            oneLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
            oneLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        // sheduleTimeDataPicker constraints
        sheduleTimeDataPicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        sheduleTimeDataPicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        sheduleTimeDataPicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        // oneView constraints
        oneView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        oneView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        oneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        oneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }
    func setContentView(content: OneModel) {
        self.oneLabel.text = content.oneName
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This is class OneModel:

```
import UIKit
struct ListNameLabel {
    static var oneText = ""
}
struct OneModel {
    var oneName: String
    static func fetchView() -> OneModel {
        return OneModel(oneName: ListNameLabel.oneText)
    }
}
```

This is class OneViewController:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
class OneViewController: UIViewController {
    var mainView = MainView()
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupNavigationBar()
        setupView()
    }
    
    // MARK: NavigationBar
    private func setupNavigationBar() {
        let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backBarButtonItem.image = ListImages.chevronImage
        backBarButtonItem.action = #selector(backBarButtonItemTapped)
        backBarButtonItem.target = self
        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
        navigationItem.title = ""
    }

    // MARK: View
    private func setupView() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        // mainView constraints
        mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        // fetch
        mainView.setContentView(content: OneModel.fetchView())
    }
}

// MARK: Back
extension OneViewController {
    @objc func backBarButtonItemTapped() {
        let vc = TwoViewController()
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
    }
}

// MARK: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
extension OneViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
        print(#function)
    }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```